# Ajax отправка формы не работает

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

ajax отправка формы н работает, выдает в консоле ошибку как на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 btnSubmit.onclick = function(){
 // Получение ID формы
 var formID = 'price_form';
 // Добавление решётки к имени ID
 var formNm = $('#' + formID);
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'assets/snippet/ajax.php',
data: formNm.serialize(),
 success: function (data) {
 // Вывод текста результата отправки
 $('#message').html(data);
 setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').html(' ');
                    },5000);
                    location.reload();
 },

 error: function () {
 // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
 $('#message').html('Ошибка');
  setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').html(' ');
                    },5000);
 }
 });
 return false;
 };
</script>
```

сама форма

```
<form id="price_form" action="" name="price_form">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="3">

                        <div class="data-left">
                            <label for="">Укажите сумму выплаты, не менее 20 Р</label>
                            <input type="text" min="20" name="sum_user">
                        </div>
                        <div class="data-left">
                            <label for="">Ваш баланс:</label>
                            <span class="balance">120 Р</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="data-left small">
                            <label for="">Укажите счет:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="invoice">
                        </div>
                        <div class="data-left small">
                            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn-submit">Произвести выплату</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

решил, сделал в ajax.php вот такой код подключения к базе и заработало все

```
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/index.php';

define("IN_PARSER_MODE", "true");

@include('config.core.php');
    if (!defined('MODX_CORE_PATH')) define('MODX_CORE_PATH', $_SEVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/');
```